# High System Load Elasticsearch - Magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.3.p1

We are running Magento 2.4.3-p1 with Elasticsearch (ElasticSuite provided from the theme vendor)
Elasticsearch is using most of the system resources and making the website extremely slow.

**curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'**

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "my-cluster",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 407,
  "active_shards" : 407,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 1,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 99.75490196078431
}
```

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: this is consuming memory on your local or on live server? also server is ubuntu?